# Error on Scriplet Include in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I recently found that the support for static includes `<%@include file="reuse.html"%>` and scriptlets have been discontinued with Tomcat 8. I understand why this was done, but I cannot understand how they would remove this feature in it's entirety without providing a similar alternative. Please note that I understand the differences between a dynamic and a static include and that a static include is compiled directly into it's containing page which offers some performance benefits.

Further more is it possible to adjust the compiled jsp's? If I wanted to declare an additional utility or object alongside the servletcontext, request and response on the compiled jsp?

Comment: I recently found that the support for static includes "<%@include file="reuse.html"%>" and scriptlets have been discontinued with Tomcat 8.   Can you share where you found this??

Comment: I tried migrating a project from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 and my pages started throwing compiler errors. I cannot point you to a single reference confirming this, but I can confirm that scriptlets have been deprecated for quite some time now and they don't appear to be working in Tomcat 8 out of the box. There might be a way to enable it though, but the documentation is quite sparse atm.

Comment: As you migrated from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 and it failed. Just think does it really possible that Apache community will force all the Java world to remove scriptlets to move in Tomcat 8. And deprecated does not means it will fail, deprecated means there is something new available then existing.

Comment: The point you raise above is exactly my question. I also know what deprecated means and that deprecated modules are eventually removed in it's entirety. Scriptlets have been deprecated for a few years now.

Comment: @Grep, Scriptlets are not deprecated. They're not going to be removed. They're obsolete but they're not going anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) JSP Specification 2.3 {http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-spec/} Includes and scriples are supported

2) Tomcat 8 Supported JSP Specifications 2.3 {http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html}

Tomcat 8 support the includes and scriplets.

Update the description with proper investigation it is going to misleads the Java developers.

Comment: Thanks, long story is that Tomcat 8 in Eclipse is not picking up my tag uri which was in an include. This only appears to happen when starting up Tomcat 8 via Eclipse, but appears to work when deployed directly to Tomcat 8. I have reverted back to Tomcat 7 for now until they sort out Eclipses issues with JDK 8 and Tomcat 8.